# No prepositions for German years?

Tags: usage, preposition, time

I wonder how is it possible that we would be able to use this sentence without any preposition or complement while it implies a dative case and we must use a preposition (such as *im*) or at least a complement (such as *Jahr* in this case) to complete the meaning!

> Wir haben 1999 geheiratet.

Comment: Don't overthink it. While _in_ + year is becoming more common in German, too (clearly influenced by English and still considered a mistake by many), traditionally a German year does not require a preposition.

Comment: Ok @Ingmar! but it  even does not mention the word "jahr", does it occur only for sentences with obvious definition (like this) and only in spoken language?

Comment: Es kann nur ein Jahr sein.

Comment: Ok, @c.p.! so could we use a sentence like this without the word "Jahr" in written language, only because of this fact that the sentence's definition is clear?!

Comment: If the meaning's ambiguous, you're free to use "Im Jahr 2012" or similar, but it's not strictly required, in both spoken and written language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different languages, different grammar.

In English, a year typically does not stand alone. Most notably, if somehing happened **in a year,** this is rendered by using the preposition *in.* An alternative is to say ‘in the year …’ or others.

> David Bowie died *in 2016.*
>
> It was in the year 2016 that David Bowie died.

French does something entirely analogous using the preposition *en.*

> David Bowie est mort *en 2016.*
>
> C’était en l’an 2016 que David Bowie est mort.

Finnish only really uses a construction along the lines of *being the year* for similar sentences:

> David Bowie kuoli *vuonna 2016.*

And a similar version is known for Latin where the construction is — at least, according to my experience — *anno MMXVI.* No example sentence because I do not speak Latin.

German, on the other hand, does not need the qualifier *in a year* except for certain situations in which misunderstandings may occur (although they typically still wouldn’t) — such as years lower than 30. Instead, the year is simply put into the sentence as is, no preposition needed. An extended form of ‘in the year …’ still exists, however.

> David Bowie starb 2016.
>
> David Bowie starb im Jahr(e) 2016.

(The dative-*e* is optional but often heard because using *im Jahre* gives something a gravitational, historical sound.)

This is just the way German grammar works. For comparison, here is a German translation of the second paragraph just to show how similar the languages work in the background with the exception of the lack of a preposition. The bolded part is identical — note how it uses a preposition and the dative case as expected.

> Auf Englisch steht eine Jahreszahl typischerweise nicht alleine. Insbesondere wird, wenn etwas **in einem Jahr** geschah, dies durch die Präposition *in* ausgedrückt. Alternativ kann man ‘in the year …’ oder ähnliches sagen.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, using a year without preposition is the standard way in German, your example sentence is completely correct. One also sometimes reads *in 1999*, but I think that this is the English construction creeping into the German language. Alternatively you could also expand it to *im Jahr 1999*.

Comment: I am only leaving this here because it mentions that *in 1999* can actually be found, even though it sounds wrong to me.

Comment: It _is_ wrong, although unfortunately becoming more common.

Comment: @Ingmar, it is wrong until it is right.